# SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number. How to find out the exact value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an INSERT statement with more than 100 columns. Testing one by one I was able to find out which value was causing the error. But what if I had an even bigger statement with hundreds of values? Is there a way to find out which column is causing the problem?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ..., COLUMN300) VALUES ('A', 'B', ..., 'AZ');
```

```
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> create table test (a number, b number);

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> insert into test values ('123','12x3');
insert into test values ('123','12x3')
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Bobby

Answer (score 1):

Your error message should contain a line number and a column number. SQL*Plus happily takes that and places an asterisk under it (see Bobby's answer), but you can see this line and column number for yourself in nearly any other client. It's part of the error that is returned.